# How to convert negative integers to binary in Ruby

Tags: ruby, binary, integer, type-conversion

Question 1: I cannot find a way to convert negative integers to binary in the following way. I am supposed to convert it like this.

```
-3 => "11111111111111111111111111111101"
```

I tried below:

```
sprintf('%b', -3) => "..101" # .. appears and does not show 111111 bit.

-3.to_s(2) => "-11" # This just adds - to the binary of the positive integer 3.
```

Question 2: Interestingly, if I use online converter, it tells me that binary of -3 is "00101101 00110011".

What is the difference between `"11111111111111111111111111111101"` and `"00101101 00110011"`?

Comment: You can just invert the bits of a positive number to get it's opposite

Comment: Please ask one question per post.

Comment: Also, please clarify the rules of conversion; currently I can’t think of any giving `11111111111101` for `-3`.

Comment: @mudasobwa that's _two's complement_.

Comment: @Stefan ...on systems where long int is 32-bit, yes.

Answer (score 11):

Packing then unpacking will convert `-3` to `4294967293` (2<sup>32</sup> - 3):

```
[-3].pack('L').unpack('L')
=> [4294967293]
```

---

```
sprintf('%b', [-3].pack('L').unpack('L')[0])
# => "11111111111111111111111111111101"

sprintf('%b', [3].pack('L').unpack('L')[0])
# => "11"
```

Comment: Great, it works!  but what does pack('L') and unpack('L')[0] do in this case?

Comment: @NobyFujioka, Check the [documentation for `Array#pack`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-pack) or [`String#unpack`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-unpack).

Comment: It worth to mention that the above will produce the result of length 32 on 64bit arch only.

Comment: @mudasobwa, According to the documentation, `L` stands for `32-bit unsigned, native endian (uint32_t)`

Comment: Oh, indeed, I messed things up. I meant that probably the requested value of length 32 is OK for 64bit only. Anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
> 32.downto(0).map { |n| -3[n] }.join
#=> "111111111111111111111111111111101
```

**Note:** This applies to negative number's only.